# Typesafe config load from java.util.prefs.Preferences

Tags: scala, config, typesafe

I'm trying to figure out how to properly instantiate a [Config](https://github.com/typesafehub/config)  instance using a `java.util.prefs.Preferences` object.

The API exposes a `ConfigFactory.load()` method that takes a `java.util.Properties` parameter, but for the life of me I can't figure out how to do the `Preferences` to `Properties` conversion.

Do you guys have any hints?

P.S. I get the preferences object as a parameter from an external context and modifying it to something more convenient is not really an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be no direct way to do it. Implementing `ConfigParseable` to add new kinds of file formats/APIs [is *very* explicitly not supported](https://github.com/typesafehub/config/blob/master/config/src/main/java/com/typesafe/config/ConfigParseable.java#L12-L16).

The easiest thing I can think is to write your own method for converting `Preferences` to `Properties` recursively, using `childrenNames()` and `keys()`.